# window.scrollTo with setTimeout goes into infinite loop but works fine without setTimeout

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, scroll, settimeout, infinite-loop

I am writing a script that would scroll down the page to load it completely for further processing, with following very basic function, scroll jumps to the bottom but it fails to load everything in between

```
while(document.documentElement.scrollTop <= document.body.scrollHeight-500){
     window.scrollTo(0, document.documentElement.scrollTop+500);
}
```

so I have modified it with `setTimeout` so it would scroll it more slowly and give time for the page to load its stuff.

```
while (document.documentElement.scrollTop <= document.body.scrollHeight - 500) {
setTimeout(
    function() {
        window.scrollTo(0, document.documentElement.scrollTop + 500);
    }, 300);
}
```

Now it ends in an infinite loop, I am assuming due to async jumping out of while somehow.

**How do I modify the above script to scroll it down slowly so it would load everything? Or just force the page to load everything in some other way**

Comment: The while loop blocks the execution, and the timed function is never executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to put it into an `async` function, and `await` a Promise that resolves after 300ms inside the `while`:

```
const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
(async () => {
  while (document.documentElement.scrollTop <= document.body.scrollHeight - 500) {
    window.scrollTo(0, document.documentElement.scrollTop + 500);
    await delay(300);
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

`setTimeout(func, n)` queues `func` to be caled in (at least) *n* ms.

so your second approach is basically

```
while (document.documentElement.scrollTop <= document.body.scrollHeight - 500) {
  addAnotherTimeout();
}
```

The code inside the loop has no influence to the condition of the loop, that's why you get an infinite loop here.

Here a recursive version (kind of):

```
var scrollTimeout;
function scrollElement(){
    clearTimeout(scrollTimeout);
    if(document.documentElement.scrollTop <= document.body.scrollHeight-500){
        window.scrollTo(0, document.documentElement.scrollTop+500);
        scrollTimeout = setTimeout(scrollElement, 300);
    }
}

// start the scrolling:
scrollElement();
```

The part with the `clearTimeout()` at the beginning of the `scrollElement()` is not required for the loop/recursion itself, but to prevent multiple concurrent loops.

If you start a second loop and the previous one isn't finished yet, kill the previous one.

Comment: *"n will always be >= 10ms"* Hum... nope. There is a 4ms throttle but that's only effective when nesting level of callbacks is more than 5 levels depth. [Timer initialisation steps • 11](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#timer-initialisation-steps). Historically, this throttle was indeed set to 10ms in some browsers, but that was already only for after some nesting levels. However, that doesn't change the fact that indeed, this will alwyas at least fire on the next event loop.